# Unable to zip more than one thousand files

Tags: php

This function returns a result set (filenames) and zip them up for a user to save on their desktop.

```
function getFiles() { 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set("display_errors", 1); 
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');  
 $result = null;
 $ZIPresult = null;
 $cleanup = null;
 $output = null;
$fileName = 'SearchResult.zip';
//remove old zip if any
 $cleanup = shell_exec("/bin/rm -f SearchResult.zip");
 error_log("SHELL OUTPUT=>" . $cleanup, 0);
 //test
 if (empty($_POST['DBSite'])) { return null; } 
 $mydir = MYDIR; // set from the CONSTANT 
 $dir = opendir($mydir); 
 $DBSite = $_POST['DBSite']; 
 $getfilename = mysql_query("select /*! SQL_CACHE */  filename from automation_search where site='" . $DBSite . "'") or die(mysql_error()); 
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($getfilename)) { 
 $filename = $row['filename']; 
 $result .= '<tr><td><a href="' . basename($mydir) . '/' . $filename . '" target="_blank">' . $filename . '</a></td></tr>'; 
 $ZIPresult .= basename($mydir) . '/' . escapeshellarg($filename).' ';
}

if ($result) {
$result = "<table><tbody><tr><td>Search Results.</td></tr> $result</table>";
$output = shell_exec("/usr/bin/zip -R SearchResult.zip ". $ZIPresult ." 2>&1 ");
error_log("SHELL OUTPUT=>" . $output, 0);
error_log("ZIP FILENAME=>" . $fileName, 0);

if (file_exists($fileName)) {
//header for forced download
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($fileName));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fileName));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($fileName);
    exit;
    }
}

return $result;
}
```

It works only for less than 1,000 files (approximately). It's as if a memory limit is hit and the list of files is output to screen.

No errors are in `Error.log`. The ZIP file is not created I tried changing my ZIP command line from

`shell_exec("/usr/bin/zip SearchResult.zip ". $ZIPresult ."  ");` to

`shell_exec("/usr/bin/zip -R SearchResult.zip ". $ZIPresult ." 2>&1 ");`

No difference. What am I missing?

Comment: Take care to escape SQL arguments as well, e.g. `$_POST['DBSite']`.

Comment: If you `shell_exec` for zip does not work (strictly check the return value, compare with the manual page of the function), you might run into a problem with too many arguments. Instead passing the list of files in arguments, you can use `-@` and pass the files via STDIN, one file per line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're likely hitting the maximum numbers of characters allowed for command line arguments. You might want to use PHP's [built-in ZIP-support](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.zip.php) for your desired task.

And on a side note: if your script is accepting user input, you'd probably want to escape it. The assignment `$DBSite = $_POST['DBSite']` should make use of [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

---

**EDIT:** Since `ZipArchive` is unavailable, there is another option you can consider:

[Open a pipe](http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php) to the ZIP binary and pass the `-@` option. This will read filenames from `STDIN`. You can then write the filenames to be included to this pipe.

```
$p = popen('/usr/bin/zip -@ -R SearchResults.zip', 'w');

foreach ($files as $filename)
   fwrite($p, $filename . "\n");
pclose($p); // Important. Handle needs to be closed with pclose()
```

Comment: The new ZipArchive() library/class is not available on our production environment so I chose to use the Unix utility ZIP instead.

Comment: Using `popen` did the trick. Thank you. Accepted and voted up.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably hitting the command line size limit (which I don't know exactly what is, but it should be some thousand characters).

Split your task into several ones: first create the zip file with a couple hundreds of files, then issue more commands to add to the existing zip file.